# "Pa. man bagged deer Wal-Mart lot deer" Is This Headline Grammatical or Sensical?

Tags: grammaticality

http://news.yahoo.com/charges-pa-man-bagged-deer-wal-mart-lot-145951272.html

I just cannot parse this headline.  I understand the story - a fellow was standing in a Wal-Mart parking lot, saw a deer he liked, shot it from across the highway, and is now being charged for being reckless, but I cannot make sense of the headline.  Am I missing something, or is it really nonsensical?

Comment: It's as grammatical as a headline is likely to get but If I had written or typeset that headline, I would have included a comma or a dash so that it read like this: **"Pa. man bagged deer - Wal-Mart lot deer"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "PA" is the abbreviation for Pennsylvania
- "bagged" means shot

I think there is an extra "deer" in there though :-)

Comment: Ah, you mean it should have read "Pa. man bagged Wal-Mart lot deer" instead?  That would make somewhat more sense.  I understood the "Pa." and "bagged", but that didn't help.

Comment: I think the part of the headline that restates "Wal-Mart lot deer" is making a point and repeating it, with the deer's location, for emphasis and was done intentionally.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: You mean like in the song? _Bagged a deer, a Wal-Mart deer; Re, a drop of golden sun..._

Comment: @J.R., *Me, I was appalled by this, Fa, that deer had long to run...* yes, like that! :-)

Comment: Accepted because removing the first "deer" makes the headline make sense, but if @KristinaLopez had posted her comment as an answer, I might have gone with that.

Comment: Thanks, @user41416, always glad to help, even if I missed out on some points! :-)